# Youtube API playlistItems extremely slow

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I am testing out the Youtube API and I am noticing the playlistItems is very slow. It takes around 7 seconds for me to fetch the list of items in the query.

I tested this in the API explorer and notice the same thing, it tells around 7 seconds for the query execution time.

I tried reducing the maxResults to 1, still takes the same time.
I tried changing the part to contentDetails, still same issue.

You can test it out using this link in the browser:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&access_token=YYYYYYYYYYYYYY&maxResults=50

Replace the X's with a watchHistory playlist ID for example and the access_token with a token.

Is there a better way of getting the items in the playlist?

Comment: Nothing you can do. YouTube is huge and API (if you're using ```json``` is too slow for me too)